'CDI(Contexts and Dependency Injection' error in Eclipse New Versions 2024
My current projects run on Java 8 and I have made the configurations for this. While building projects; I get the error "errors running builder 'CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) Builder' on project MyProject. java.lang.object org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.javaelement.getelement info()". I checked on the Eclipse forums but it doesn't work I couldn't find anything useful. I cannot disable it because my projects use the CDI infrastructure.
Can you help me?

Please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

Perhaps you need to report this as a bug to JBoss support.
